# Twig IF statement parses negative integer as positive

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to use a Twig (version 2.x) if/elseif/else statement to display some text based on the balance of an order, but it seems that Twig is parsing a negative integer as a positive one.

```
{% if (order.balance) > 0 %}
You have EUR {{ order.open_amount }} left to pay!
{% elseif (order.balance) < 0 %}
You have paid to much, the remainder will be deposited into your account.
{% else %}
You have paid, thank you.
{% endif %}
```

order.balance is fed into Twig as an integer and can be either negative, 0 or positive.

The piece of code however has the following result:

order.balance = 0
Expected: You have paid, thank you.
Actual: You have paid, thank you.

order.balance = 29999
Expected: You have EUR 299,99 left to pay!
Actual: You have EUR 299,99 left to pay!

order.balance = -10001
Expected: You have paid to much, the remainder will be deposited into your account.
Actual: You have EUR -100,01 left to pay!

The logic I am following is more or less as described in an example here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

What am I missing here?

Comment: Code works as is - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/znpn4y)

Comment: Hmm, I see it. Maybe it is because I am applying the twig code through a WYSIWYG editor in my browser, rather than in a template file in the back-end?

Comment: Shoudln''t make a difference, guessing your using `{% include template_from_string(my_template) %}` to run the code then?

Comment: No, I am setting up an Environment feeding it an ArrayLoader. Then I put the template in with createTemplate, where the input from the WYSIWYG editor is the template. It is then rendered feeding all the data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have just inverted your condition or the sentence you want to display, or your logic, even.

```
{% if order.balance < 0 -%} {#- that condition was > 0 -#}
    You have EUR {{ order.open_amount }} left to pay!
{% elseif order.balance > 0 -%} {#- and this one was < 0 -#}
    You have paid to much, the remainder will be deposited into your account.
{% else -%}
    You have paid, thank you.
{% endif %}
```

Here is a fiddle representing this: https://twigfiddle.com/r3cdr8

Comment: Yeah except that a positive number does mean there is still an amount to be paid and a negative means the customer is going to get an amount credited.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought as well. Except it is not :P

Answer (score -1):

I tried putting in the 3 different options as 3 different IF statements and then things work out fine, better to avoid if/elseif/else structures where ever possible with Twig?

```
{% if order.balance > 0 %}You have EUR {{ order.open_amount }} left to pay!{% endif %}
{% if order.balance < 0 %}You have paid to much, the remainder will be deposited into your account.{% endif %}
{% if order.balance == 0 %}You have paid, thank you.{% endif %}
```

Do it like this and it works perfectly.

Comment: Why should you avoid `if/else/elseif`?